# hcitool shows iOS13's public Mac address without pairing

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, hci

iOS 13 follows "LE privacy" rule, it sends BLE beacon packets with random MAC address, which keep changing periodically. But "hcitool scan" command shows iOS's bluetooth public MAC address. I guess it violates "LE privacy" rule.

I checked BLE sniffer log, iOS just advertise with random MAC address and manufacture data. iOS does not send public MAC address. I cannot find any packet with public MAC address.
Do you know how hcitool get iOS's public MAC address?

Scan side:
 Linux raspberrypi 4.19.93-v7l+,
 Bluez 5.37

Beacon side:
 iPhone8, iOS13.3, Setting app, Bluetooth setting screen.

These devices have not paired before.

Answer (score 2):

"hcitool scan" use Bluetooth classic (BR/EDR).
"hcitool lescan" use Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE).

On Bluetooth classic, "LE privacy" rule is not applied. Public MAC address is exchanged.